# Custom annoations take abstract keyword

Tags: java

When trying to define a custom annotation in java, along with the public keyword we are also allowed to specify it as abstract. I wonder what purpose does it solve since annotations can't be extended.

Comment: Well, technically annotations are interfaces (`@interface`) so they're kind of already `abstract`. You can also add `abstract` to the properties as well. I suppose it depends on how Java creates instances of the annotations on runtime. I have no idea how this works though :X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotation types are declared as interfaces, and `abstract` on interfaces doesn't mean anything:

> [9.1.1.1 abstract Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html#9.1.1.1)
>
> Every interface is implicitly abstract. This modifier is obsolete and should not be used in new programs.